# I tried to download the file with Spring boot and React

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

When React sends data, I tried to make a code to read and download files based on the data, but an error occurred.

Code for sending data from react.

It was created to render the object list containing the path to download, and it worked normally.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {selectFileList.map((object) => (
          <div key={object.index} className={classes.fileDown}>
            <label htmlFor="file_down" className={classes.fileLabel}>
              <FileDownloadIcon />
              <div className={classes.fileDownSmall}>
                <a
                  id="file_down"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    color: "white",
                  }}
                  onClick={() =>
                    fileDownload(object.bd_file_path, object.bd_file_nm)
                  }
                >
                  {object.bd_file_nm}
                </a>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I confirmed that all the data are normally included.

```
const fileDownload = async (path, name) => {
    const sendData = {
      file_path: path,
      file_nm: name,
    };
    await dispatch(fileAction.fileDownload(sendData))
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", name);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
      });
  };
```

This is the code of Spring Boot that reads the file through the path and sends the data.

```
    @PostMapping("/fileDownload")
    public void fileDownload(@RequestBody BoardFileDTO dto ,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Path path = Paths.get(dto.getFile_path()).toAbsolutePath();
        File file = path.toFile();
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", Files.probeContentType(path));
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dto.getFile_nm());
            
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.blob is not a function

This error has occurred

There was no error in SpringBoot, and it was not possible to verify that the data was successful.

I'm using a translator, so the way I talk may be awkward.

Where did it go wrong? Was it a problem with the repetitive rendering? At least it didn't happen there, but I don't know where it started.

Comment: There may be some places with different names because I erased and modified some of them while typing here, but this is not the case in the actual code.

Comment: `.then((response) => response.blob())`   Please print response here  Guess that the corresponding object is not an output stream, so there is no blob method

Comment: like `.then((response) => {console.log(response); return response.blob();})`

Comment: The same error still occurs

Comment: `.then((response) => {const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));});`
I solved it with this
But I can't read the data about blob yet. Only text files work normally.

Comment: Check if the `Content-Type` of your response is `application/octet-stream`
Maybe you should call the `setContentType` method instead